# Javascript function to get input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

I have written the code with multiple buttons each with a different value.
I am trying to get that value in a javascript function.

```
  <form action="https://www.bing.com" method="get">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="q" id="field" autofocus>
    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x1" name="x1" value="Bing"> 
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x2" name="x2" value="Google">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x3" name="x3" value="Yahoo"> 
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x4" name="x4" value="Duck">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x5" name="x5" value="Ask"> 
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x6" name="x6" value="Aol.">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  var input = document.getElementById('field');
    var x = document.getElementById('x1').value;

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    if(x=="Bing") {

    var redirect = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + input.value; }

    window.location = redirect;
  });
</script>
```

Here input submit sets the value only when it is clicked right ? If I try to name all submit buttion ids as xx then I can get what button is clicked in the function. I want to execute different redirects once the corresponding submit button is clicked. (**Multiple Submit Actions**:
This problem is not duplicate, it is specific to JS and this situation)

Comment: what is `xx`? Some control you missed out...or...is it a typo?

Comment: This link http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-submit.phtml can help you. In short it says: if($_REQUEST['Operation'] == 'Update')
{
  //Do update here..
}
else
if($_REQUEST['Operation'] == "Insert")
{
  //Do insert here
}

Comment: @deostroll I wrote that to say that xx could be anything among x1,x2...  bad way.

Comment: My bad, I missed that bit... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this. works for me

```
    <input class="input" type="text" name="q" id="field" autofocus>
    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x1" name="x1" value="Bing"> 
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x2" name="x2" value="Google">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x3" name="x3" value="Yahoo"> 
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x4" name="x4" value="Duck">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x5" name="x5" value="Ask"> 
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x6" name="x6" value="Aol.">
    </div>

</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

$(".button").on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var x = $(this).attr("value");
var redirect = "" 
if (x=="Google")
{

 window.location = "https://google.com/search?q=" + $(".input").val();

}

});

</script>
```

expand the if condition for more search options.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the following: make the buttons regular buttons `<input type="button" ...`. Then set on click events for each button to do whatever it is you want, e.g. `$('#x1').on('click', function(){...});`. If at some point you want to submit the form, you can always do `$('#formid').submit()` which will send the information in the text input.

Perhaps this might be of some help: http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/boohfpsu/4/

```
<form id="myform" action="https://www.bing.com" method="get">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="q" id="field" />
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="button" class="mybutton" id="bing-button" name="x1" value="Bing"/>
        <input type="button" class="mybutton" id="google-button" name="x2" value="Google"/>
        <input type="button" class="mybutton" id="yahoo-button" name="x3" value="Yahoo"/>
        <input type="button" class="mybutton" id="duck-button" name="x4" value="Duck"/>
        <input type="button" class="mybutton" id="ask-button" name="x5" value="Ask"/>
        <input type="button" class="mybutton" id="Aol-button" name="x6" value="Aol"/>
    </div>
</form> 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bing-button').on('click', function(){
        alert("bing was clicked");
        alert("the value of the text input is " + $('#field').val());
        alert("I'm now going to submit the form");
        $('#myform').submit();
        alert('submitting the search');
        var search_string = "https://google.com/search?q=" + $('#field').val() + "\"";
        alert("the search string is: " + search_string);
        window.location.href = search_string;
    });
});
```

If you comment out the form submit you do a google search. Otherwise you do a bing search.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain a little bit more like if I have to write code for first button. Also, could there be some other way, this method may not be scalable -- if I increase buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The script will fail to work the way you've written it. Here are some guidelines:

1. handle the submit button's click event. Store its `value` somewhere, say in another variable, `cache`.
2. In the form's submit event...retrieve the above value (`cache.value`) and then perform your redirection logic...

Edit:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var input = document.getElementById('field');
var cache = {}; //global to store value...

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input.button');

for(var x = 0, j = buttons.length; x < j; x++){
    var i = buttons[x];

    i.addEventListener('click', function(){        
        cache.value = this.value;        
    }, false);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log(cache.value);
});
```

This is not the best way to do it...but you'll get there eventually ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/1btuez9v/1/ (based on [Jonathan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022786/145682) fiddle).

Comment: I got it. thx. Could you kindly give a bit of code just for starting ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use data attributes on the buttons and on click update the form action...

```
<form action="https://www.bing.com" method="get">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="q" id="field" autofocus />
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" class="button" id="x1" name="x1" value="Bing" data-target="https://www.bing.com" /> 
        <input type="submit" class="button" id="x2" name="x2" value="Google" data-target="https://google.com/search?q=" />
    </div>
</form>
<script>
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var input = document.getElementById('field');

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        form.action = this.dataset.target;
    });
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log(form.action);
});
</script>
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1btuez9v/

Answer (score 1):

try below code it should work

```js
var input = document.getElementById('field');


$('.button').click(function(ev){
   
   if(ev.target.value == "Google"){
      location = "https://google.com/search?q=" + input.value; 
   }//add more cases here with 'else if'
  window.location=location;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://www.bing.com" method="get">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="q" id="field" autofocus>
    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x1" name="x1" value="Bing"> 
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x2" name="x2" value="Google">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x3" name="x3" value="Yahoo"> 
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x4" name="x4" value="Duck">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x5" name="x5" value="Ask"> 
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="x6" name="x6" value="Aol.">
    </div>
  </form>
```